# «Quando c'è l'alta marea anche i relitti galleggiano. Noi siamo i relitti»

Tags: sentences

Vi risulta che quest'espressione esista e significhi coerentemente qualcosa?

«Quando c'è l'alta marea anche i relitti galleggiano. Noi siamo i relitti»

Se sì, qual è l'origine?

Comment: You might find this answer interesting too: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230520/origin-of-a-rising-tide-lifts-all-boats/230689?noredirect=1#comment493786_230689

Answer (score 2):

Sembra che la frase sia stata coniata da JFK riferendosi alle dinamiche di crescita dell'economia  e il sogno americano:

> - Forza alimentatrice di tale ascensore sociale – la famosa “[l'alta marea che fa galleggiare tutte le barche](http://www.smartweek.it/per-far-galleggiare-tutte-le-barche-ci-vogliono-le-istituzioni-disuguaglianza-nellamerica-del-xx-secolo/#)" di J.F. Kennedy – è l’aumento della produttività del fattore lavoro.

L'espressione nella domanda sembra una elaborazione di questa più nota e penso  si riferisca al fatto che, se l'economia riprende, ne beneficiano anche le entità più inefficienti (i relitti).

La frase è stata pronunciata da Matteo Salvini a Ballaro, riferendosi alla difficile condizione economica italiana.